# Can pre-print be published as "working paper" after the peer reviewed and revised manuscript has been accepted for publication by the journal?

Tags: publications, ethics, copyright, preprint

A colleague wishes to publish a pre-print as a "working paper" after the revised manuscript has gone through the peer review process and accepted for publication.

The rationale is that firstly, there is a long wait (over a year) until the manuscript is published by the journal; and, secondly, the publisher allows the author to deposit the pre-print at any time in an institutional repository.

My question is: Is a working paper series an "institutional repository"? Shouldn't the pre-print be submitted to the working paper series *prior to* peer review and journal acceptance?

Comment: I don't understand the rationale. If the author is allowed to "deposit the pre-print at any time in an institutional repository", then why doesn't he just do that? He could, for instance, make the pre-print available on his website until the paper is published. What's the benefit of putting it in a working papers publication?

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't understand the rationale too. My understanding is that a working paper series is a "publication outlet" and not an "institutional repository". Is that common understanding, or am I wrong?